# MVC OnException to return Json Result to Display Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

When an error occurs my OnException() is being fire and the error is being logged properly from my ajax call.

The issue is the errorMessage I am returning in the Json result is NOT displaying and result.data is "".

Can you see what I am doing wrong with my code?

```
        $.post("/Admin/CreateOrganization", createOrganizationModel)
        .done(function (data) {
            if (data.success) {                       
                //Everything is good 
            }
            else {
                swal(
                    'Failed to create organization.',
                    data.errorMessage,
                    'error'
                );
            }
        })
        .fail(function () {
            swal(
                'Failed to create organization. Please reload and try again',
                '',
                'error'
            );
        });
```

Here is my OnException:

```
        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        // Log to database...

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { success = false, errorMessage = "An error has occurred." },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };

            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            Server.ClearError();

            RedirectToErrorView();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

I fixed it as I was posting this question.

I had "error" in my Data = ... instead of "errorMessage"

It is showing the errorMessage now in my sweet alert message box.